# Phalcon get parameters are not working with lighttpd

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, phalcon, lighttpd

This is my `Lighttpd` config file for `phalcon`

```
$HTTP["host"] == "www.phalcon.dev" {
server.document-root = "C:\devtools\lighttpd\htdocs\phalcon\test\public"
url.rewrite-if-not-file = ( "^/(.*)$" => "index.php?_url=/$1" )
}
```

`Urls` are working fine but I am unable to get the parameters after `?`

> www.phalcon.dev/test/mymethod - is working
>
> www.phalcon.dev/test/mymethod?var=1 - not working showing 404 error

I think there is problem in `lighttpd` config rewrite but I am unable to figure it out

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer on Phalcon forum. [Here](http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/6468/phalcon-get-parameters-are-not-working-with-lighttpd#C17470) is the Link. I am posting it here, might be it will help somebody.

```
url.rewrite-if-not-file = ("^/([^.?]*)\?(.*)$" => "/index.php?_url=/$1&$2","^/([^.?]*)$" => "/index.php?_url=/$1")
```